# Why is R Studio giving an error for large dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, updates

I downloaded a new version of R Studio (2023.03.0) yesterday and am now running into an error. Whenever I try to call a column (using a $) from a large dataframe, I get the following error:

```
Error in order(typeScores, scores) : argument lengths differ
In addition: Warning message:
In completions$type == .rs.acCompletionTypes$DATAFRAME & !completions$context %in% :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The following code (constructed for the post here https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13018 by someone else who faced the same error) duplicates the issue:

```
library(dplyr)

generate_dataframe <- function(n_rows, n_columns) {
  set.seed(42) # Setting the seed for reproducibility
  
  random_column_generator <- function(n_rows) {
    col_type <- sample(c("character", "numeric", "boolean", "factor"), 1)
    
    if (col_type == "character") {
      return(sample(c(LETTERS, NA), n_rows, replace = TRUE))
    } else if (col_type == "numeric") {
      return(sample(c(rnorm(n_rows, mean = 0, sd = 1), NA), n_rows, replace = TRUE))
    } else if (col_type == "boolean") {
      return(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE, NA), n_rows, replace = TRUE))
    } else if (col_type == "factor") {
      values <- sample(c(-1:1, NA), n_rows, replace = TRUE)
      labels <- c("Negative", "Neutral", "Positive")
      return(factor(values, levels = c(-1, 0, 1), labels = labels, exclude = NULL))
    }
  }
  
  random_string <- function(length) {
    return(paste(sample(c(LETTERS, letters), length, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
  }
  
  df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = n_columns, nrow = n_rows))
  
  for (i in 1:n_columns) {
    df[[i]] <- random_column_generator(n_rows)
  }
  
  colnames(df) <- replicate(n_columns, random_string(sample(1:8, 1)))
  
  return(df)
}


# Generate random large dataframe
generated.df <- generate_dataframe(n_rows = 5e4, n_columns = 4e3)
```

If you type "generated.df$" the error will appear. My question is, why is this error occurring? It doesn't seem to be changing how my code is running--what does it mean? And lastly, is this a bug in the newest R studio?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it seems to be an error in the RStudio version (nothing to do with your R code) for which a solution was found, but it's not included yet in the current version. So you have to either downgrade or live with the error until it's included in a new RStudio version.

Comment: I'm unclear as to the purpose of this question. As noted by Kevin in the GH issue thread, there was an internal error with the IDE, and the SO community would not be able to readily know what the issue was. I think your questions would have a far greater chance of being answered there than here.

Comment: Not reproducible on OS X 10.14.6 RStudio 2021.09.2+382 "Ghost Orchid" Release (fc9e217980ee9320126e33cdf334d4f4e105dc4f, 2022-01-04) for macOS
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.10 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36 R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)

Answer (score 0):

It could simply be that you do not have enough memory (RAM) installed in your system. Try using a smaller dataframe and see if that helps - before you run out and buy more memory.

You could also use Task Manager (or top) and see what your memory usage looks like.